# Hosted service for EOSIO

Tags: node, private-blockchain

Is there any ready to setup EOSIO installed cloud service available so that I can create a private chain by connecting few of such nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out dfuse On Demand Networks. We can operate the network on your behalf. Here's a link to get some more info: https://www.dfuse.io/en/blog/let-dfuse-launch-your-on-demand-network

Comment: Can you share details regarding pricing?

Comment: Really depends on your unique needs. Best to follow along with what it says in the above article (grab a free account thru app.dfuse.io and then submit some info) and someone will reach out to you shortly to get you set up.